# Vintage Braun speaker crossover capacitors

Tags: replacement

I know that non-polarized capacitors are used in a speaker crossover. The attached Braun schematic (L-910, 1968) shows 2 different symbols for non-polarized caps. Any ideas what the difference is ? Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain (I'm old enough to be unsure, now.) But I think the open capacitor symbol (plate area hashed not filled) means what we used to just call a "bipolar" that was made from two polar capacitors. Had to be done that way for large-valued capacitance. You can check this by just looking by-eye. If you see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duLFH.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzl4u.png) than that's what the symbol means. The filled-plate capacitor symbol just meant a single "nonpolar" and these always were of smaller values because that's what was available.

Comment: So my reading of this L 910 speaker schematic would make me expect to see two caps bound together for three of those and one of them just a single cap. A total of 7 individual, physical capacitors is what I'd expect to see. Have you opened it up, yet? Or are you just considering an attempt to replicate their design (which is a lot more than just the schematic itself.) I'd also expect those inductors to be *huge* air core and wound with large diameter enameled wire on a large radius.

Comment: It appears that theory may be correct. The 'hatched' symbol capacitors for low and mid frequencies are indeed 2 caps paralleled. The 12 ufd and the 4.7 ufd are singles, with the 4.7 apparently being a film type. Thank you for your insight, much appreciated !

Comment: The inductors are quite large, yes. The speakers are quite impressive and definitely worthy of a restoration. I suppose the capacitor type is less critical than the value, ultimately...

Comment: Thanks. I was hesitant to imagine the 12 ufd as a double, too. But the diagram made me expect to see a double there. It is low enough in value. So that makes sense. The schematic itself may have been written by the designer who at the time expected to see a double-unit for the 12ufd. And it is possible the first few were produced that way. But that manufacturing soon changed that. Anyway, thanks for the feedback. My memory needs a boost from time to time. ;) But I definitely remember that we schematically injected the idea into a reader that they should create a bipolar from 2 polars here.

Answer (score 2):

Different types of capacitors.

The large ones must be elecyrolytic caps, and the smaller would likely be a plastic film capacitor or similar.

Comment: More likely perhaps C4 is a paper dielectric part for that era (often yellow cylinders).  Agreed the larger caps are very likely non-polarised electrolytics which may be back-to-back polarised electrolytics or more likely a single cap that has insulating layers deposited in both plates rather than just one.  If you’re looking to replace these it’s worth having a look at what modern parts are available with similar spec.